# How can I find out if my service has started

Tags: android, android-service

In my code, I start my service conditionally like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
context.startService(intent);
```

Can u please tell me if it is possible to find out if I have started the SAME Service before so that I don't start my service TWICE?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

a service won't be started two times if it's already running, in fact even if you call multiple times startService() you need only one stopService() to stop it.

see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html#StartingAService) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29).

Comment: The system calls onCreate() method when the service is first created, to perform one-time setup procedures (before it calls either onStartCommand() or onBind()). If the service is already running, this method is not called.  So that means we can do logic in boolean to know about service started or not

Answer (score 5):

Check this:

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
    if ("com.example.MyService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;}
```

@bigstones: I don't know how, but I have a service that it can be created how many times as you like (maybe because I create inside it various runnable objects).

Comment: When I use the above code, It only shows all system services not the service which I created